# Ending Questions with だ

Tags: particles, questions, intonation

Is it ever proper to end questions with だ? For instance:

> 誰だ？
>
> どんな食べ物は好きだ？

I have been told it was correct and incorrect by many parties, but I've always learned to just raise the ending intonation to denote an inquiry.

Comment: Yes. If you want to raise a discussion, it is proper. Proved. The rest is purely subjective and contextual.

Comment: `どんな食べ物は好きだ？` -> You'd use が, not は. どんな食べ物**が**好きだ？Cf: 「何**が**ありますか？」(not 何は~~) 「誰**が**来たの？」(not 誰は~~)

Answer (score 6):

Interrogative phrases ending in だ (with the exception of dialects) are used to ***demand information***.

As in the following:

- 誰だ！・何者だ！ - "Who!", "Who goes there!"
- どこだ！ - "Where!", "Where is it!"
- いつだ！ - "When!", "When is it!"
- 何だ！ - "What!"
- 何のつもりだ！ - "What are you trying to do!", "What's your intention!"
- おい！そこでなにしてるんだ！ - "Hey! What are you doing over there!"
- 誰に向かって物言ってるんだ！ - "Who do you think you're talking to!"

Comment: I somewhat understand you, but almost every question phrase "demands information", doesn't it? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Question

Comment: In a way I think it's a difference between a demand and a request. Like the difference between お名前はなんですか (I'm requesting you to provide your name) and 名前は何だ (I'm demanding that you tell me your name).

Answer (score 1):

か is the usual way to ask a question, but it is quite acceptable to drop the か if you use a proper "questioning" intonation. You could just say "好き?" if you used the proper intonation.

Answer (score 0):

... 誰だ？ -- could be a regular question.

... 誰だ？ -- could be a  [rhetorical question].  See
[Is a sentence ending with 誰だ but without か a question?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/39693/16344)

どんな食べ物が好きだ？  -- is typical of an adult speaking to a child.

Kind-of like (in English) : [Do you like this cake?]  --vs.--  [You like this cake?]
[Is this good?]  --vs.--  [This is good?]